# Intellisense not working in VSCode - OmniSharp Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, msbuild, omnisharp

Intellisense has stopped working for me and whenever I run VSCode this error comes up in the OmniSharp Log.

```
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/Users/leogaunt/Documents/Programming/Unity/Cube Stack/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
/Users/leogaunt/Documents/Programming/Unity/Cube Stack/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
/Users/leogaunt/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.1/.omnisharp/1.37.0/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1178,5): Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /Users/leogaunt/Documents/Programming/Unity/Cube Stack/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
```

I have tried re-installing the plugin, and re-intsalling VSCode but it hasn't worked.

I know I have .NET Core installed as I am a Mac user and I know this because when I type `dotnet --version` in terminal it outputs:

> 3.1.401

I am programming in Unity and am creating a game for iOS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the mono path to always, in C# extension config.

Answer (score 9):

## For anyone that uses VSCode v1.67.2 dotnet v3.x.x and OmniSharp v1.25.0 (or v1.23.17 and above).

**The above accepted answer does not solve the issue.**

The simplest thing to do is downgrade ms-dotnettools.csharp (C# Extension), the only issue is if you downgrade to any version above v1.23.16 it gives you "Can't install 'ms-dotnettools.csharp' extension because it is not compatible with the current version of Visual Studio Code (version 1.67.2)"

***I suggest to downgrade it to version 1.23.16 and restart vscode.***

Your Intellisense should start working.

**My Environment**
dotnet v3.1.417
VSCode v1.67.2
C# Extension v1.25.0 (now downgraded to v1.23.16)
Running in Remote Container on a Mac host.
*Yes I am using 3+ year old dotnet version. It's a legacy software, it happens, everyone has skeletons in their systems ;)*

Answer (score 7):

Edit: For latest version

1. Make sure you have **Mono** installed [Link to Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/)
2. Make sure you have **.Net sdk** installed [Link to .Net SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)
3. Open VS Code
4. Go into **Settings**
5. Search and **tick** **useOmnisharp**
6. Search and **untick useModernNet**

Answer (score 3):

I downgraded the VS Code's C# extension to 1.24.3 from 1.25.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem after fetching Unity from a git repository.
For me it worked to reset the .Net Version in Unity.
Edit -> Project Settings -> Api Compatibility Level

Switched that back and forth, restarted VSCode. The .csproj-file will file out all the missing dlls.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by uninstalling all SDK's and installed the **older** 4.7.1, then everything worked instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here's how I fixed it:

I added all projects to the solution file (`dotnet sln add <project name>`) and opened the project in vs code by passing the path to vscode from terminal
(`code <project path>`).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem on MacOS Ventura, something was broken in the installation of Omnisharp. The solution was to simply delete and reinstall Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having this issue in latest VSCode v1.8 and C# extension is v2 and you're getting similar error, then try to install an older version. Go to Extensions -> C# -> Right click -> Install another version and select the latest v1.x.x -> Reload VSCode -> Done

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and searched for a solution to this problem.
**To fix:**
1- Upgrade vscode.
2- Delete all extensions associated with c#.
3- Install the latest version of the C# extension.
4- Run CMD 'pkill -f OmniSharp' to stop all omnisharp processes.
5- Restart vs code and wait for some time until the Omnisharp related process loads in the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **VS Code**, the **C# Dev Kit** extension might be causing the issue. You may need to downgrade the package to version `1.0.14`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest C# extension and VS Code, I was able to get OmniSharp running when I saw this from [C# - VS Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp).

> **How to use OmniSharp?**
>
> If you don’t want to take advantage of the great Language Server features, you can revert back to using OmniSharp by going to the Extension settings and setting dotnet.server.useOmnisharp to true. Next, uninstall or disable C# Dev Kit. Finally, restart VS Code for this to take effect.

Answer (score -1):

The error says that OmniSharp is looking for **Version=v4.7.1**. You may want to install the [latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers) of it.

Comment: I'm using macOS and the .NET 4.7.1 is only for Windows